# appending JSON data to different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to use a switch statement to build the markups based on the retrieved feed. Although I'm able to retrieve the data, I wonder if it's correct to use two `$(data.value.items).each(function (index, item) {`   to append the feed's titles to a select box as well as an unorder list. Any better way of doing the same thing?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.zzz.com/text.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      item_html = parseData(feedformat, data)
      var nextarea = $this.next('.area');
      nextarea.append(item_html).slideDown();
    },
    error: function () { 
      area.html('fail'); }
});

function parseData(type, data) {
    var item_html ='';
    switch(type) {
        case 'thisfeed':
            item_html +='<select>';

            $(data.value.items).each(function (index, item) { 
                item_html += '<option>'+item.title+'</option>'; 
            });

            item_html += '</select>';
            item_html += '<ul>';

            $(data.value.items).each(function (index, item) {
                item_html += '<li>'+item.title+'</li>
            });

            item_html += '</ul>';
            break;
       }
     return item_html;   
    }
```

Comment: on first look , please wrap your ajax `url` within `quotes` ' '

Comment: three cheers for XSS holes!

more seriously, consider using a minimal templating language (e.g. mustache) to build markup - if `item.title` is user-generated, you really, really, really want to be escaping that properly.

Comment: @candu - how would getting data with ajax be an XSS hole? I realize that if the data isn't validated on the serverside *when it comes in*, it would be, but the example doesn't show that, only clientside code, which poses no risk.

Comment: @candu - would you please tell me what risks does the code have?

Comment: @user35295 - if `item.title` is from user-generated content, an attacker can input titles like `<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>`.  this allows the attacker to execute arbitrary JavaScript whenever other users view that content: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

@adeneo - this is a common vector for XSS holes, even if the code as written doesn't strictly contain one, and I figured it was worth mentioning on the off chance OP hadn't seen them yet.

Comment: @candu - fair enough, but it's really irrelevant here, as we don't know what the OP is doing on the serverside and the correct place to validate the data would be when it comes in, not when it's fetched with ajax at a later time and outputted, at that time the data should be clean, and going by the logic that it could be a XSS hole, you'd have to post that warning on every question that has something remotely to do with ajax.

Comment: @candu Okay, I'll take your advice. I get feeds from some news sites, and use data attributes to get the feed's url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do both in the same loop, something like this

```
$.ajax({
    url      : 'http://www.zzz.com/text.json',
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function (data) {
        var item_html = parseData(feedformat, data)
        var nextarea  = $this.next('.area');
        nextarea.append(item_html).slideDown();
    },
    error: function () { 
        area.html('fail'); 
    }
});

function parseData(type, data) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'thisfeed':
            var select = $('<select />'),
                ul     = $('<ul />');

            $(data.value.items).each(function (index, item) { 
                var option = $('<option />', {text : item.title}),
                    li     = $('<li />', {text : '.......'});

                select.append(option);
                ul.append(li);
            });
       }
    }
    return select.add(ul);
}
```